# How do I use jQuery to add a class to a parent element when a child is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have menu structure like below:

```
<ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-1564 current_page_item menu-item-5230" id="menu-item-5230"><a href="http://artofsujatha.wpstag.sirahu.net/curriculam-vitae/" title="Curriculam VItae">Curriculam VItae</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-5231" id="menu-item-5231"><a href="http://artofsujatha.wpstag.sirahu.net/bio/" title="Bio">Bio</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-5232" id="menu-item-5232"><a href="http://artofsujatha.wpstag.sirahu.net/artist-statement/" title="Artist Statement">Artist Statement</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I click any LI elements within the UL, I need to add class "active" to the UL element.
How can I do this in jQuery?

Comment: Thanks for your answers.but when i click that li page get refreshed so the class name is not set. But the clicked LI's class name set as "current-menu-item". based on that i need to set classname for it's corresponding UL. so how do it this one?

Comment: are you using wordpress? what function are you using to generate the menu? this would help us to avoid javascript for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this one.It works

```
<script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
       $('ul.sub-menu li').each(function (){
    var linktext = $(this).attr('class');
   if( $("linktext:contains('current-menu-item')") ) {
       $(this).parent('ul').addClass('current');
    }
});
});
     </script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$('ul.sub-menu li').click(function(){
 $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: If you're going to add it to every `LI`, why not just add the callback to the `UL`?

Comment: @Farray, if `UL` has a big padding, clicking on an empty space inside UL would activate it... better to put the event on the `LI`, also it seems more logical.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('li.menu-item').click(function () {
    $(this).parent('ul').addClass('active');
});
```

Based on your comment about the page refreshing, here is a solution that should work:

```
$(function() {
    $('li.current-menu-item').parent('ul').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the onclick event of the LI to:-

```
$(this).parent().attr('class', 'active');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li.current-menu-item").parent().addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
$(function() {
    function updateMenu() {
        $('ul.sub-menu.active').removeClass('active');
        $('li.current-menu-item').parent('ul.sub-menu').addClass('active');
    }

    $('li.menu-item').click(function(e) {
        // prevent page from redirect
        e.preventDefault();

        // set new current-menu-item
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('current-menu-item');
        $(this).addClass('current-menu-item');

        // and update active menu according the current-menu-item
        updateMenu();
    });

    updateMenu();
});
```